# Save variables to file at runtime

Tags: metaprogramming, julia

I'm looking for some functionality in Julia comparable to Matlab's

```
save('myfile.mat', 'myvar1', 'myvar2')
```

For example, using HDF5.jl, it is easy to do

```
@write filename myvar1 myvar2
```

But this requires that I know exactly which variables I want to write to the file.

I'd like to be able to choose which variables to write *at run time*, in a function scope, and specify their names using symbols or strings.

```
vars = [:myvar1, :myvar2]
@write filename vars
```

What would be the best way to accomplish this?

EDIT

I know that I can use `save` from JLD.jl as `save("file.jld", "myvar1", myvar1)`. But I want to be able to save a list of variables that are not known at compile time, allowing a single call to `save` (or similar):

```
if condition
    myvar1 = 1
    vars = [:myvar1]
else
    myvar1 = 1
    myvar2 = 2
    vars = [:myvar1, :myvar2]
end

# what goes here?
save(filename, vars...)
```

Answer (score 2):

You may want to take a look at the [JLD package](https://github.com/JuliaLang/JLD.jl), which builds on HDF5 with better support of user-defined Julia types. Both HDF5 and JLD provide functions for `save` that take run-time names for variables.

Comment: I know I could provide run-time names for variables. But I want to choose the list of variables to save at run-time. All the solutions I see using `save` etc require the variable name to be written in the source. Please see my edit.

Comment: @MicahSmith You can calculate these variables using `eval()`. For example: `myvar1=1; vars=:myvar1; save("save.jld", string(vars), eval(vars))`

Comment: @张实唯 Thanks, this is almost the missing piece. I wrote that I'm looking for a solution that might work in *function scope* and `eval(vars)` will fail outside of the global scope.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `serialize` and `deserialize`:

```
vars = Dict()
if condition
   myvar = 1
   vars[:myvar1] = myvar1
else
   myvar1 = 1
   myvar2 = 2
   vars[:myvar1] = myvar1
   vars[:myvar2] = myvar2
end

f = open( filename, "w" )
serialize( f, vars )
close( f )
```

to read:

```
f = open( filename, "r" )
vars = deserialize( f )
close( f )
```

if you don't need to save variable names you can use array instead of dict: `vars = []`

Comment: This will work but it should be noted that using `serialize` / `deserialize` for more than transient data persistent is not recommended since the data format is not stable across Julia versions.